Finding interval $[a, b]$ s.t. $f(x) \in [a, b]$ for all $x \in [a, b]$
I am trying to find a numerical approach to the least root of $f(x) = x^3 - x -1$, using the fixed-point iteration method. In particular, if $p$ is a root of $f$, I know
$$
g(x) = x - f(x) = -x^3 + 2x + 1
$$
is such that $g(p) = p$, i.e. $p$ is a fixed point of $g$. Thus, the problem of finding roots of $f$ can be expressed as the problem of finding fixed points of $g$.
I must find an interval $[a, b]$ such that $g(x) \in [a, b]$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. This is due to the fact that a theorem ensures that if $g$ is continuous and satisfies the aforementioned property, the existence of a fixed point in $[a, b]$ is guaranteed. That $g$ is continuous is trivial (it's a polynomial).
How does one find an interval $[a, b]$ s.t. $g(x) \in [a, b]$ for all $x \in [a, b]$? Furthermore, for any general function $f$, how does one find such interval?

Are you sure that is the function $g$ you want to use? We know that the root is between $1$ and $2,$  but $g(1)=2, g(2)=-3,$ so it seems like you are going to need $a,b\in(1,2).$ But there are other functions that might work better, like $g(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2}.$

How do you intuitively come up with a function that "works"? Feel free to add your response as an answer.

Intuitively, $|g'(x)|$ needs to be less than $1$ in some region of the zero. That's all the guide I have.

I tested your $g$ and it doesn't work. It can be proven that the root is somewhere in $(1.3, 1.4)$, so we need to pick an interval $[a, b]$ with $a < 1.4$. However, we also need $| g'(a) | < 1$. But $g'(x)$ is increasing for $x > 0$ and $|g'(1.4)| \approx 1.23$. So we cannot choose an interval which at the same time contains the root and bounds $g'(x)$ around zero.

Yeah, I wasn't sure it would work, but there are surely other possibilities.

I still appreciate your suggestion. Thanks!

Another alternative might be $$\frac1{x^2-1 }=\frac12\left(\frac1{x-1}-\frac1{x+1}\right).$$

Found a solution: $g(x) = (x+1)^{1/3}$. Comes from re-arranging $f(x) = 0$, just as your own $g$. Will answer my own question with the solution. Thanks for the guidance!

Let us study $f$ before proposing a function.
$f'$ is a quadratic function with $a > 0$ and roots $\pm \frac{\sqrt{3} }{3}$.
From this readily follows that $f'(x) < 0$ only at $(-\sqrt{3}/3, \sqrt{3}/3  )$,
which means $f$ is decreasing in that range and increasing everywhere else.
Furthermore,
\begin{equation*}
    f\left( \sqrt{3}/3   \right) = 3^{\frac{3}{2}}/9 - \sqrt{3}/3 - 1  < 0
\end{equation*}
entails there is a root $r$ in $(\sqrt{3}/3, \infty) $, and
\begin{equation*}
    f\left( - \sqrt{3}/3  \right) < 0
\end{equation*}
means it is the only root. And since $f(1.3) < 0, f(1.4) > 0$, the intermediate value theorem guarantees $r \in (1.3, 1.4)$.
We need to propose a function $g$ with fixed point $r$ which satisfies:

$g(x) \in (a, b)$ for all $x \in (a, b)$, where $(1.3, 1.4) \subseteq [a, b]$.
$|g'(x)| \in (0, 1)$ for all $x \in (a, b)$.

Consider that
\begin{equation*}
    f(x) = 0 \iff x = \sqrt[3]{x+1} =: g(x)
\end{equation*}
Since
\begin{equation*}
    g'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2} }
\end{equation*}
we know $0 < g'(x) < 1$ for all $x$. Furthermore, since $g'(x) > 0$ for all $x$,
$g(x)$ is increasing. Then, observing that $g(1.3) \approx 1.32, g(1.4) \approx 1.33$,
guarantees that $x \in [1.3, 1.4]$ for all $x \in [1.3, 1.4]$. Thus,
$g$ satisfies all the conditions which ensure convergence of the
fixed-point iteration method.

You forgot the $\frac13$ in the derivative. $$\frac13\frac1{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}}$$
